# Calculating the probability in $m$ steps of a Homogeneous Markov Chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I have the next problem:

Consider a homogeneous Markov chain $\{X_n: n = 0,1,2, ... \} $ with state space $E = \{0,1,2, ... \} $, with the following transition probabilities where $ 0 <\theta <$ 1

$$p_{ij} = \begin{cases} 
      \theta &\mbox{if } j=i+1\\
      1-\theta&\mbox{if } j=i\\
      0 & \mbox{otherwise.}
   \end{cases}$$

and initial distribution $v_0(0)=1$, ie starts in the zero state with probability 1.

Explicitly calculate the probability of transition in $ m $ steps $ p_ {ij } $ for any state $ i, j \ in E $.

This is my solution

Let the powers of the transition matrix:

$$P=\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
  1-\theta & \theta & 0 & 0 & ...\\ 
  0 & 1-\theta& \theta & 0 &...\\
  0 & 0 & 1-\theta& \theta & ...\\
  \colon& \colon &\colon &\colon & \ddots
  \end{array}\right]$$

and :

$$P^2=\left[\begin{array}{cccccc}
  (1-\theta)^2 & 2\theta(1-\theta)   & \theta^2          & 0                   & 0        & ...\\ 
  0            & (1-\theta)^2        & 2\theta(1-\theta) & \theta^2            & 0        &  ...\\
  0            & 0                   & (1-\theta)^2      & 2\theta(1-\theta)   & \theta^2 & ...\\
  \colon       & \colon              &\colon             & \colon              & \colon   & \ddots
  \end{array}\right]$$

$$P^3=\left[\begin{array}{cccccc}
  (1-\theta)^3 & 3\theta(1-\theta)^2   & 3\theta^2(1-\theta) &\theta^3              & 0        & ...\\ 
  0            & (1-\theta)^3          & 3\theta(1-\theta)^2 & 3\theta^2(1-\theta)  & \theta^3        &  ...\\
  0            & 0                     & (1-\theta)^3        & 3\theta(1-\theta)^2  & 3\theta^2(1-\theta) & ...\\
  \colon       & \colon                &\colon               & \colon               & \colon   & \ddots
  \end{array}\right]$$

and we note that each has a binomial coefficient Newton with $x=1-\theta $ and $y=\theta $

$$1=(x+y)^m= \sum_{k=0}^m {m \choose k}(1-\theta)^{m-k}\theta^k = (1-\theta)^m+...+{m \choose j}(1-\theta)^{m-j}\theta^j+...+\theta^m$$
Then the transition probabilities in $ m $ steps are:

$$p_{ij}^{(m)} = 
   \begin{cases} 
      (1-\theta)^m &\mbox{if } j=i\\
      {m \choose j}(1-\theta)^{m-j}\theta^j  &\mbox{if } i<j<i+m\\
      \theta^m &\mbox{if } j=i+m\\
      0 &\mbox{otherwise.} 
   \end{cases}$$

am I correct?

Comment: How many and how many columns does P have ? Are the numbers equal ?

Comment: $P$ is an infinite transition matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite correct. All OK until you translate your binomial expansion into your answer: $k$ should translate to $j-i$ instead of $j$. Also, cases $1$ and $3$ are just instances of case $2$, so we can simplify accordingly.

$$p_{ij}^{(m)} = 
   \begin{cases} 
      {m \choose j-i}(1-\theta)^{m-j+i}\theta^{j-i}  &\mbox{if } i \leq j\leq i+m\\
      0 &\mbox{otherwise.} 
   \end{cases}$$

Comment: Another question @Mick, where can I found excersices at this level?

Comment: @XIvan Hi. "Introduction to Probability Models" by Sheldon Ross is an easy-to-read text on this with examples and exercises.